# XSLT Select specific nodes below current

Tags: xslt

I am trying to solve this for someone else and have run into an issue myself.

I have the XML:

```
<Process>
  <name>Pro1</name>
  <duration>Dur1</duration>
  <time>Time1</time>
  <name>Pro2</name>
  <duration>Dur2</duration>
  <time>Time2</time>
  <name>Pro3</name>
  <duration>Dur3</duration>
  <time>Time3</time>
  <name>Pro4</name>
  <duration>Dur4</duration>
  <time>Time4</time>
  <name>Pro5</name>
  <duration>Dur5</duration>
  <time>Time5</time>
</Process>
```

Output:

```
<Process>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro1</name>
    <duration>Dur1</duration>
    <time>Time1</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro2</name>
    <duration>Dur2</duration>
    <time>Time2</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro3</name>
    <duration>Dur3</duration>
    <time>Time3</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro4</name>
    <duration>Dur4</duration>
    <time>Time4</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro5</name>
    <duration>Dur5</duration>
    <time>Time5</time>
  </Process_Info>
</Process>
```

Using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name ="varProcess" select ="Process"/>

  <xsl:template match="Process">
    <xsl:element name="Process">
      <xsl:for-each select ="name">
        <xsl:variable name ="posName" select ="position()"/>
        <xsl:element name ="Process_Info">
          <xsl:copy-of select ="."/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$varProcess/duration[$posName]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$varProcess/time[$posName]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the `<duration>` and `<time>` nodes will not always be present and the `<name>` is the only guarenteed node. Therefore if one is missing my `position()` selecting fails.

How can I change the XSLT to allow for it to work even when `<duration>` and/or `<time>` does not exist.

My theory would be that you select the two nodes below the current name node and if they are `<duration>` or `<time>` they are copied? But not sure how that would implement either.

Example of current output causing issue.

Input:

```
<Process>
  <name>Pro1</name>
  <duration>Dur1</duration>
  <time>Time1</time>
  <name>Pro2</name>
  <duration>Dur2</duration>
  <time>Time2</time>
  <name>Pro3</name>
  <duration>Dur3</duration>
  <time>Time3</time>
  <name>Pro4</name>
  <time>Time4</time>
  <name>Pro5</name>
  <duration>Dur5</duration>
</Process>
```

Output:

```
<Process>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro1</name>
    <duration>Dur1</duration>
    <time>Time1</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro2</name>
    <duration>Dur2</duration>
    <time>Time2</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro3</name>
    <duration>Dur3</duration>
    <time>Time3</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro4</name>
    <duration>Dur5</duration> <!-- Should be in the below process_info -->
    <time>Time4</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro5</name>
  </Process_Info>
</Process>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick, albeit a bit 'manual' in approach. There may be more elegant ways to achieve this

```
<xsl:template match="Process">
    <xsl:element name="Process">
        <xsl:for-each select ="name">
            <xsl:element name ="Process_Info">
                <xsl:copy-of select ="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="firstSib" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[1])" />
                <xsl:variable name="secondSib" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[2])" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstSib='duration'">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$secondSib='time'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <time>SomeDefaultValueForMissingTime</time>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstSib='time'">
                        <duration>SomeDefaultValueForMissingDuration</duration>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <duration>SomeDefaultValueForMissingDuration</duration>
                        <time>SomeDefaultValueForMissingTime</time>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Input :**

```
<Process>
    <name>Pro1</name>
    <duration>Dur1</duration>
    <time>Time1</time>
    <name>NameMissingDuration</name>
    <time>TimeMissingDuration</time>
    <name>NameMissingTime</name>
    <duration>DurMissingTime</duration>
    <name>NameMissingBoth</name>
    <name>NormalName</name>
    <duration>NormalDuration</duration>
    <time>NormalTime</time>
</Process>
```

**Output**

```
<Process>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>Pro1</name>
    <duration>Dur1</duration>
    <time>Time1</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>NameMissingDuration</name>
    <duration>SomeDefaultValueForMissingDuration</duration>
    <time>TimeMissingDuration</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>NameMissingTime</name>
    <duration>DurMissingTime</duration>
    <time>SomeDefaultValueForMissingTime</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>NameMissingBoth</name>
    <duration>SomeDefaultValueForMissingDuration</duration>
    <time>SomeDefaultValueForMissingTime</time>
  </Process_Info>
  <Process_Info>
    <name>NormalName</name>
    <duration>NormalDuration</duration>
    <time>NormalTime</time>
  </Process_Info>
</Process>
```

Comment: I'll give it a short while to see if any other, in your own words, 'more elegant' approaches are created else will use this and mark accordingly. Definately learnt from your response already though, wasn't aware of following-sibling for starters :)

Comment: Marked as answer because your response has provided me with the tools required for the XSLT. I will post up my adaption removing the un-required default fields which strips the size down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution without `xsl:if`.

This demonstrates using the [`generate-id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#function-generate-id) function for testing for node equality in selecting the first *time* (or *duration*) element which follows the current *name* element and whose first preceding *name* element is the current element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Process">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="generate-id()"/>
    <Process_Info>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::duration
                           [generate-id(preceding-sibling::name[1]) = $this]
                           [1]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::time
                           [generate-id(preceding-sibling::name[1]) = $this]
                           [1]"/>
    </Process_Info>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Another interesting answer with a learning curve for me also, thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Based off nonnb's response so all credit goes to him, the final XSLT being used. My mistake for not including in the question that I don't need a filler node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Process">
    <xsl:element name="Process">
      <xsl:for-each select ="name">
        <xsl:element name ="Process_Info">
          <xsl:copy-of select ="."/>
          <xsl:variable name="firstSib" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[1])" />
          <xsl:variable name="secondSib" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[2])" />
          <xsl:if test ="($firstSib='duration') or ($firstSib='time')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test ="($secondSib='duration') or ($secondSib='time')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```